# Use lag(x,1) or lag(x,-1) for dynamic regression?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a simple yet somehow confusing question about dynamic regressions and lagged independent variables. I have 3 time series and I want to study the effect of 3 indedendent variables (namely PSVI, NSVI, and BTC_Ret) from the previous week on the current weeks bitcoin log returns. I want to analyse for example if a negative change in PSVI (Positve Sentiment Index) from the previous week can tell us something about the direction of the BTC returns in the following week.

I came across the lag function which can do exactly do that.

If I understand the function correctly, I would use the the lag function in combination with the dyn$lm function from the package dyn to get the results I want.

My code would then look as follows:

```
test1 <- dyn$lm(BTC_Ret~lag(PSVI,1)+lag(NSVI,1)+lag(BTC_Ret,1))
summary(test1)
```

Am I right to assume that I need **to use lag(x,1)** and **not lag(x,-1)**?

And should I use dyn$lm to study the effect or is there a better way to do all of this?

My data looks as follows:

```
structure(c(0.151825062532955, -0.179352391776254, -0.171610266403897, 
0.0159227765884022, -0.353420091085592, -0.0179223189753976, 
0.260710954985742, -0.0878045204765083, 0.17494222283881, -0.183889954532262, 
-0.15249960475038, 0.0325479482522972, -0.216135243885031, 0.0258548317723122, 
0.170469815313808, 0.0552681180119521, 0.0676987678252168, 0.0247151614282206, 
-0.101373110320685, -0.0244444101458825, -0.363995910827583, 
-0.819549195465083, -0.311532754839479, -0.661660753934884, -0.036159476713393, 
-0.0116417252109642, -0.219357256430676, -0.386169350367107, 
-0.468384245564164, 0.226420789220966, -0.2366560332375, 0.2425676656972, 
-0.351430535471613, -0.287492079068963, 0.548071569094531, -0.228973857164721, 
-0.139490538928287, 0.247548840497568, -0.361502742177194, 0.0604938285432965, 
0.619445016304069, 0.0947076213861557, -0.887137767470338, 0.0485516007581502, 
0.0429273907756451, -0.701341407090506, 0.34191134646093, -0.428167056300805, 
-0.298917079322128, 0.517537828051947, 0.0474069010338689, -0.118044838446349, 
-0.414289228784203, 0.143198527419672, 0.0733053148180489, 0.0131259707878403, 
-0.106103445964187, 0.107827719520595, -0.604074345624302, 0.444400965939648
), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("BTC_Ret", "PSVI", 
"NSVI")), .Tsp = c(2018, 2018.36538461538, 52), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You are right that `lag(x,1)` refers to the previous date, assuming that values are sorted by date and you are using `dplyr::lag`, if that's your question. If you use `-1` you should get an error, `! \`n\` must be a positive integer, not a double vector of length 1.`

Comment: I think the main part of the question is about using lag and that is a programming question.

Comment: You should not be using dplyr's lag here.  See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tt` defined in the Note at the end (copied from the question) we use the following.

ts class is normally used with R's lag.  The -1 in that means move the series 1 forward so that the previous value lines up with the current row.  There is more information in `?lag`.

Do not use dplyr's lag which does not work with ts class and furthermore is different and uses the opposite convention or if you want to load dplyr use `library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))` to ensure that you are using R's lag.

```
library(dyn)

test1 <- dyn$lm(BTC_Ret ~ lag(PSVI,-1) + lag(NSVI,-1) + lag(BTC_Ret,-1), tt)
```

These alternatives also work:

```
Lag <- function(x, k = 1) lag(x, -k)
test2 <- dyn$lm(BTC_Ret ~ Lag(PSVI) + Lag(NSVI) + Lag(BTC_Ret), tt)

test3 <- dyn$lm(BTC_Ret ~ lag(tt, -1), tt)
```

### Note

```
tt <- structure(c(0.151825062532955, -0.179352391776254, -0.171610266403897,  0.0159227765884022, -0.353420091085592, -0.0179223189753976,  0.260710954985742, -0.0878045204765083, 0.17494222283881, -0.183889954532262,  -0.15249960475038, 0.0325479482522972, -0.216135243885031, 0.0258548317723122,  0.170469815313808, 0.0552681180119521, 0.0676987678252168, 0.0247151614282206,  -0.101373110320685, -0.0244444101458825, -0.363995910827583,  -0.819549195465083, -0.311532754839479, -0.661660753934884, -0.036159476713393,  -0.0116417252109642, -0.219357256430676, -0.386169350367107,  -0.468384245564164, 0.226420789220966, -0.2366560332375, 0.2425676656972,  -0.351430535471613, -0.287492079068963, 0.548071569094531, -0.228973857164721,  -0.139490538928287, 0.247548840497568, -0.361502742177194, 0.0604938285432965,  0.619445016304069, 0.0947076213861557, -0.887137767470338, 0.0485516007581502,  0.0429273907756451, -0.701341407090506, 0.34191134646093, -0.428167056300805,  -0.298917079322128, 0.517537828051947, 0.0474069010338689, -0.118044838446349,  -0.414289228784203, 0.143198527419672, 0.0733053148180489, 0.0131259707878403,  -0.106103445964187, 0.107827719520595, -0.604074345624302, 0.444400965939648 ), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("BTC_Ret", "PSVI",  "NSVI")), .Tsp = c(2018, 2018.36538461538, 52), class = c("mts",  "ts", "matrix"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the example above I used the function   stats::lag    since I'm dealing with time series data.  My question still remains. In your answer you used the lag(x,-1). Am I right to assume that I should use lag(x,-1) to study the effect of the previous weeks independent variables on todays dependent variable?

Comment: I think, I finally figured it out. I indeed have to use stats::lag(x,-1) since i want to move the independent variable forward by one so that previous line aligns with the current line of the dependent variable!